# arg_parse None or list to pandas read_table

Tags: python, pandas, argparse

I am using pandas to process space-delimited numeric data files. Some of the files have a header row, some don't. Pandas handles this by allowing header values of *int, list of int, default 'infer'*, whereas *None* is no header. I want this information parsed on the command line, as in:

`python myscript file.txt -Header None`

This is what I've tried:

```
parser.add_argument("-Header",
    help="specify whether the data have headers",
    args+, type=str, default=['None'])
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then, I want to check whether an *int, a list of int*, or *None*, was passed:

```
if args.Header[0] != 'None':
    Header = [int(item) for item in args.Header[0].split(',')]
else:
    Header = None
```

Then I read the data,

```
df = pd.read_table(data_file, comment = "#", header=Header) # read data
```

However, I seem unable to properly pass either 'None' or 'infer'. Passing Header 0 does work, but of course the first row is treated as header instead of data.

---

EDIT:
It seems my problem isn't with arg_parse, but rather how the data are indexed by pandas when there is/isn't a header. I'm heading errors of the type:
`result = self.index.get_value(self, key)`
I'll try to work this out.

Comment: Can you use `pd.read_csv`?  I get messages that `read_table` is deprecated.  You might find that its handling of `header=None` makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks. I've now tried ````pd.read_csv with sep='\s+'```` Same result. :(

Answer (score 0):

Given the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html)

> if no names are passed the behavior is identical to header=0 and column names are inferred from the first line of the file, if column names are passed explicitly then the behavior is identical to header=None.

I would say the `pd.read_table` is not built to be used in the way you're intending. Therefor I'd suggest an if statement that breaks the call into two versions.

```
if header is None:
    df = pd.read_table(data_file, comment = "#")
else:
    df = pd.read_table(data_file, comment = "#", header=Header)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've now tried that, no luck. I'm suspecting that arg_parse is not the source of my problem.  I'll edit Q to provide more diagnostics.